# Anyway to get CPU usage from YARN History Server

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, metrics, ambari

I have already got some historical data from YARN  History Server. However, the only cpu related data are vcore/memory seconds. Is there any other way for me to calculate cpu utilization of cluster during a period of time and visualize just like this pic?[image]

It will be great if we can differentiate cpu utilization of jobs run by different user.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In short, you are looking for a **monitoring** solution that would aggregate OS metrics across the cluster -- like Ganglia, Graphite, Prometheus?

Comment: Note that the vcore X seconds and RAM X seconds were introduced by Yahoo! infrastructure teams as a way to recharge costs to their "clients" in their multi-tenant clusters. It was never meant as a monitoring solution, just as a billing solution.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Kinda like monitoring but not the same. You know there are many users using the same cluster, and some of them submit their job only during the day period. So, I want to analyse their cpu usage. I want to persuade users to not only use it during regular hours but also use during night time if they are not doing so already.

Comment: Are you not using Ambari or Cloudera manager?

Comment: @cricket_007 Using ambari, but I think Ambari could only give me a rough idea.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by rough. The recent versions of Ambari in HDP can install Grafana as well as Ambari metrics. But the numbers it collects are the same

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you, great to know that! Could Grafana or ambari metrics monitor specific user?

Comment: @cricket_007 I am just wondering if I could find a similar tool like [link](https://image.slidesharecdn.com/june30-3pm-yahoo-thrapp-160715234222/95/show-me-the-money-cost-resource-tracking-for-hadoop-and-storm-8-1024.jpg?cb=1468626175)

Comment: That looks like a proprietary Yahoo application. Sure, metrics collectors such as Metricbeat, Datadog, etc exist to give you that information on a per-user, per OS process level, but that applies to any server, not just YARN specifically